# Does VSCode support autocomplete for Mono namespaces on Mac?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, mono

I want to use VScode(1.39) with C# plugin (1.21.5) on Mac(10.14) to develop C# code with Mono(6.4 from Home-brew). I've noticed that trying to complete namespaces names works only for some namespaces contained into "System" and "Microsoft" namespaces, but not for others like "Mono".

```
using Mono. // no completion options.
using System. // only some namespaces appear.
```

Does current C# plugin for VSCode supports autocompletion on namespaces name and functions? If that is the case, to allow completion on Mono namespaces, do I have to do additional configurations?

I tried different values on Mono environment variables like:

```
MONO_PATH=/usr/local/opt/mono/lib/mono/gac
MONO_PATH=/usr/local/opt/mono/lib/mono/4.7.2-api
MONO_PATH=/usr/local/opt/mono/lib/mono/
MONO_PATH=/usr/local/opt/mono/lib/

MONO_GAC_PREFIX=/usr/local # this is suggested by Home-brew
```

Changing that do not produce any changes in the results. "Mono" namespaces are not available for completion.

Comment: The autocomplete list is maintained by Roslyn compiler running in the background, when it detects which assemblies are the references (like mscorlib) so if your project has no Mono specific references, I don't expect anything to be displayed for Mono.*. The environment variables you tried are irrelevant, so they won't help.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a .csproj including a reference to a Mono assembly and it worked as I expected.